# How do I Turn Yoshimitsu Around?

Tags: soul-calibur-5

I've scrolled through the entirely of Yoshimitsu's moves list, but I guess I've missed something because I absolutely cannot figure out how to turn him around so that he's facing away from his opponent.  The only consistent method I've found of doing this is to do the deathcopter move and fly over the opponent, but it's not very practical.

Comment: Are you sure you're not remembering Voldo as the character that liked having his back turned? Yoshimitsu very much likes to face his opponents directly.

Comment: You play it your way, and I'll play it my way, okay?

Comment: I don't know why you would get offended. You can play the game however you want. I was merely trying to provide information.

Comment: Ah, going for the ol' harakiri to victory strategy I see?

Comment: @StrixVaria Gnome wasn't offended; that was a joke.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are a few basic, reliable ways to turn Yoshimitsu around so his back is facing the enemy:

66B+K (i.e. while running forward, hit B+K) will do a leaping somersault and end up with your back turned.

66A+K (i.e. while running forward, hit A+K) will turn you around and do nothing else. Make sure you don't hold A+K too long, though, or you'll stab yourself through the stomach, committing seppuku.

Comment: That's actually the move I wanted to turn around to perform.

Answer (score -2):

The developers removed this aspect of Yoshimitsu in SC5, along with a bunch of other moves.

Comment: No they didn't. Yoshimitsu has tons of ways to turn around.